# Ruby on rails bootstrap modal window

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bootstrap-modal

I have model Post.rb with title and description

My index page.

```
Title 1
Title 2
Title 3
```

I need a description opened in bootstrap modal window in the same page

index.html.erb

```
<ul class="content">
  <%= render @posts %>
</ul>
```

_post.html.erb

```
<li> 
  <%= link_to post.title, '#myModal', 'data-toggle' => 'modal' %>

  <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel"><%= post.title %></h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <%= post.description %>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</li>
```

Comment: how do you want to open description opened in bootstrap modal window? on click each title individually or something else, please describe more.

Comment: @Anand each title individually, through ajax

Comment: I flagged ur post as duplicate, but later faced similar situation and realised it wasn't so simple as expected. Refer to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47079432/ror-pass-param-to-bootstrap-modal-background-doesnt-fade-out/47091344#comment81150269_47091344

Answer (score 3, accepted):

_post.html.erb

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content" id="modal_content">
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

1. create a partial `_post_content.html.erb`

   ```
   <div class="modal-header">
     <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel"><%= post.title %></h4>
   </div>
   <div class="modal-body">
     <%= post.description %>
   </div>
   ```

2.

```
<%= link_to post.title, show_modal_path(post_id: post.id), remote: true %>
```

3.

```
def show_modal
  @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
end
```

4.`show_modal.js.erb`

```
$('#modal_content').html("<%= j render 'post_content', post: @post %>");
$("#myModal").modal('show');
```

5. create route for `show_modal` ex-

get 'show_modal/:id', to: 'your_controller#show_modal', as: :show_modal_path

Comment: doesn't work undefined method `show_modal_path' for #<#<Class:0x007fc265213c28>:0x007fc265211b80>
Did you mean?  show_modal_path_url

Comment: Hmmm i just show you one example to create `show_modal` action . Here you need to create your own action and as well as its routes also

Comment: you need to replace `show_modal_path` with your own routes , you can see routes for this action by using command `rake routes`