# RoR - pass param to Bootstrap modal. Background doesn't fade out

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, ruby-on-rails-5

I display list of profiles and need to display more details about every user via the modal:

```
<%= link_to profile.full_name, { :action => :profile_modal, 
                                :profile_id_param => profile.id }, 
                              {remote: true, 'data-toggle' => 'modal', 
                                'data-target' => '#modal-window'} %>
```

Here is the container fiv for modal:

```
<div id="modal-window" class="modal hide fade" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="tue">
</div>
```

Controller action:

```
  def profile_modal
    @profile = Profile.find_by_id(params[:profile_id_param])

    respond_to do |format|
      format.js  
      # format.html
    end 
  end
```

and profile_modal.js.erb:

```
$("#modal-window").html("<%= escape_javascript(render partial: 'shared/profile_modal', locals: { profile: @profile }) %>");

$("#profile_modal").modal();
```

Modal:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="profile_modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="msgModal" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title"> 
          <% if @profile %> <%= @profile.id %> <% end %>
```

This code above passes the variable according to the `params[:profile_id_param]` value, but there are two problems:

1. After I open modal and close it, background doesn't fades in again. It remains darker, just modal itself disappears;
2. For some reason I can't pass locals to modal. As you see, I use instance variable in it, because it errors me with undefined.

What is wrong here?

UPDATE:

Treid to turn off turbolinks like this on click:

```
<%= link_to profile.full_name, { :action => :profile_modal, 
                                  :profile_id_param => profile.id }, 
                                {remote: true,  'data-turbolinks' => false, 'data-toggle' => 'modal', 
                                    'data-target' => '#modal-window'} %>
```

But didn't helped

Comment: after you close the modal you do not do a full page refresh because you are using `AJAX`, so I am thinking this could be a turbolinks problem. Are you using `turbolinks 5`? because it is not compatible with the gem `jquery.turbolinks`? https://github.com/kossnocorp/jquery.turbolinks if yes, then we need to figure out what is the `jquery` file you are using for this effect and then fix it, or even easier, just use one of this event and figure out how to fix your background https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks#full-list-of-events

Comment: @Fabrizio Bertoglio, I would also like to think its about Turbolinks, but I can not find any joints to that. Yes, I use Turbolinks 5, but not `jquery.turbolinks` gem. And my modal.js comes from `'bootstrap', '~> 4.0.0.beta'`. Only one thing I noticed that after I trigger modal to show up, modal container (`#modal-window`) in my case, gets `show` class added (modal itself also gets it). So, hm.. tried to remove it "mechanically" :)  but still not very confident in playing with js / coffee and Rails

Comment: the connection with turbolink (don't mind jquery.turbolinks) is the following. You have `bootstrap.js`. That file has a `document.ready()` statement that run only when the page refresh. You are not doing a full refresh of the page so your functions in the `bootstrap.js` do not run. Still I'll give you a better answer tomorrow. Anyway about `show` class. The best thing is removing it like that, otherwise figure out what is wrong with your `bootstrap.js`. Anyway I am making only assumptions, tomorrow I give you a better answer

Comment: @Fabrizio Bertoglio, I just remembered that turbolinks could be turned off....So tried to add `'data-turbolinks': false` but still no effect. Thanks for help, I will also try get into this deeper tomorrow

Comment: I'll dig deep better tomorrow, I think the solution is here https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/javascript/#modals and the js file responsible for this effect is this one https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/v4-dev/js/src/modal.js tomorrow I'll try to figure out what function inside there is applying a `show` class ...

Comment: Looks like I removed that `show` class, but still doesnt work.. `$('#modal-window').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
  $('#modal-window').removeClass('show')
})`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to go around this:

```
$('#modal-window').on('hide.bs.modal', function () {
  $('#modal-window').css("display", "none");
})

$('#modal-window').on('show.bs.modal', function () {
  $('#modal-window').css("display", "block");
})

$("#modal-window").html("<%= escape_javascript(render partial: 'shared/profile_modal', locals: { profile: @profile }) %>");

$("#profile_modal").modal();
```

And disable `backdrop`:

```
<%= link_to profile.full_name, { :action => :profile_modal, 
                                 :profile_id_param => profile.id }, 
                               { remote: true, 'data-toggle' => 'modal', 
                                'data-target' => '#modal-window', 
                                'data-backdrop' => "false"} %>
```

Also noticed that `#modal-window` gets z-index 1050 even after modal being closed, but this:

```
$('#modal-window').on('hide.bs.modal', function () {
  $('#modal-window').css("display", "0");
```

Didnt fixed it.

I keep this issue open for:

a) a better way to fix this

b) How to pass locals to this modal?